# Wrong indentation after installing newer Vim

Tags: vim

I installed vim using Homebrew on my Mac. Before that, I had used the pre-installed Vim.

Now my indentation is messed up.

Previously working, I had `set ts=2 sw=2 noet` in my `.vimrc`. However, this does not work anymore.

- My `.vimrc` is loaded since I have other settings in there which still work.
- When I manually invoke the above command in Vim, indentation is "correct" again, i.e. as specified.

Why does my new Vim not behave as expected? The built-in vim still works as before.

Edit 1:

As requested in the comments:

```
tabstop=8
    Last set from
    /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim
shiftwidth=4
    Last set from
    /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim
expandtab
    Last set from
    /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim
```

Edit 2:

Changing the settings here solved the problem.

Comment: `:verbose set ts? sw? et?`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that `:verbose` is my friend :-) However, can I somehow give `.vimrc` "priority" over those internal files? Or do I just edit those?